# At what point was Betazed re-taken in the DS9 Dominion war?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

[In the Pale Moonlight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_the_Pale_Moonlight) (and to my mind, the best of all DS9 episodes), it is mentioned that the Dominion capture Betazed.

As the war takes a better turn for the Federation, I don't recall any mention of when the planet was re-taken. When was it?

Obligatory: "It's a faaaaaake".

Comment: I like 'Rocks and Shoals'.

Comment: Rocks and Shoals is probably the best pure science fiction in all of DS9, exploring an alien culture and how its rules drives existence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAICT, it is never mentioned on the show.  The closest is in [The Sound of Her Voice](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Sound_of_Her_Voice_%28episode%29), which makes mention of unsuccessful attacks by 2nd fleet against Betazed.

The novel [The Battle of Betazed](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Battle_of_Betazed) covers the retaking, but beyond it being sometime in 2374, no date is mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

In the episode just before the series finale ([DS9 : Dogs of War](http://ds9.trekcore.com/media/scripts/724.txt)) Sisko, Martok, Admiral Ross and Velal mention that the Dominion forces have completely withdrawn into Cardassian space.

> INT. WARDROOM : Where Sisko is meeting with MARTOK (wearing his
> chancellor's cloak), Ross and the Romulan Commander last seen in "When
> it Rains" -- who we'll call VELAL. They're all looking over a wall
> MAP.
>
> **ROSS :** *-- according to our intelligence reports, the Dominion has
> completely withdrawn from Klingon, Federation and Romulan space. They
> seem to be forming a new defense perimeter within Cardassian
> territory.*

There were some in-universe tactical reasons for the Dominion doing this, but most likely it was also a way for the writers to tie up loose ends like liberating Betazed.

Comment: It’s Betazed. No-one cares. Just imagine the Vorta reporting this great success to the Founders. “We have taken Betazed! The Federation will be starved of empaths! When their ships face ours in battle, they will have no-one on the bridge saying ‘I sense hostility Captain’! VICTORY IS NOW IN OUR GRASP”